# Android audio streaming without MediaPlayer (need to work with buffer)

Tags: android, streaming, buffering

I have an app that plays online radio stations using MediaPlayer, but now I need to be able to record what I am listening and have a one minute buffer to re-listen.

With MediaPlayer I don't have access to the buffer so is useless to me, wich can be the best way to achieve that?

I use API >= 11.

Answer (score 0):

[Audiotrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)  allows buffer access. Go to git search on "audioboo" for android [project with  implementation](https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android/blob/master/src/fm/audioboo/application/FLACPlayer.java) of that class .